# Handle java object in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

I am using Ajax in my JavaScript and that sets an array of objects of following class in a response:

```
public class RetrieveTempSecVersions {

    private String templateName;
    private int[] versionNumber;

    public String getTemplateName() {
        return templateName;
    }

    public void setTemplateName(String templateName) {
        this.templateName = templateName;
    }

    public int[] getVersionNumber() {
        return versionNumber;
    }

    public void setVersionNumber(int[] i) {
        this.versionNumber = i;
    }
}
```

using:

```
aoRes.setContentType("text/xml");
aoRes.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
aoRes.getWriter().write(template[]);
```

Now I want to read all the elements from template array and its details into my JavaScript.

Can anyone help me in how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/)? With GWT you have a number of choices for sending objects between client and server, including [GWT RPC](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html), [RequestFactory](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html), and [JSON](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSON.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to transform your array of Java objects into something JavaScript understands. There are two obvious choices : XML (AJAX means Asynchronous Javascript And XML), or [JSON](http://json.org/). JSON is probably easier and more lightweight.

All the AJAX JavaScript libraries (JQuery, etc.) have good support for JSON. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ for example.

There are also several Java APIs to transform Java objects into JSON (look at [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for example).

You'll have to modify the content type of the response : it's not text/html, but application/json if you use JSON.

Answer (score 1):

As already said jQuery is very good for ajax manipulation.

Another good framework I liked to use was DWR: https://github.com/directwebremoting/dwr

It is quite lighter than jQuery (because only focused on Ajax calls and not components) and very easy to understand.