# how to change java object into javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, angularjs

```
ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView();
BookList<book> list=new ArrayList<book>();
list.add(new book(1,"book1"));
list.add(new book(2,"book2"));
mv.addObject("attlist", list);
```

now I want to retrieve that list object into javascript so that i could manipulate that value

Comment: JSON is one possibility. You need to try something, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173093/spring-return-json-from-controller-as-modelandview

Comment: you can use google web toolkit, see this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115225/handle-java-object-in-javascript